# как исправить [Violation] 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took 145ms?

Tags: веб-программирование

Cделал игру на Unity под Web, выложил ее на сайт смотрю в консоль и каждый раз после сохранения игры в консоли появляется это "[Violation] 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took 145ms", как это решать ? как это починить ? из за этого сохранения не всегда срабатывает.

Если нужны будут какие то файлы - пишите, что именно, я новичок в этом деле.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]